# nv-nsight-cu-cli caused Tensorflow to fail

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia, nvprof, nsight-compute

I've downloaded the newest Nsight Compute profiling tool and I want to use it to benchmark Tensorflow applications. The code I'm using is [here](https://github.com/valohai/tensorflow-example/blob/master/train.py). It runs perfectly fine when I execute it and when I benchmark it with `nvprof ./mnist.py` it had no problem at all. However, when I try to run it with command `sudo ./nv-nsight-cu-cli [path to the file]` I get the following error:

`ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I suspect that `nv-nsight-cu-cli` somehow didn't recognized the environment variable at all. Is there any fix around?

Comment: Did you fixed that problem? If no, why are you running nsight with `sudo`? Remember you need to use `sudo -E` if you want to preserve your environment variable (like LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

Comment: @RobinThoni Well I think the tool somehow does not work on Tesla P100. I tried the same program o my GTX1080 and it works perfectly fine. Any idea why it doesn't work on Tesla P100? Btw I used the one provided in cuda 10.1, still no luck

Comment: Did you run on the same machine and environment?

Comment: @RobinThoni yes it’s a network file system so everything should stay the same

Comment: But it's a different machine?

Comment: @RobinThoni not the same machine unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that GP100 is not supported by the tool at this moment.
The answer is found [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1045430/nsight-compute-/partial-profiling/):

> Nsight Compute only supports Pascal (other than GP100) and later GPUs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to search for differences in both environments:

- env variables
- `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- `/etc/ld.so.conf`
- `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*`
- cuBLAS

  - Is installation complete/not broken?
  - Is it installed at the same location on both machines?
  - Versions
- ...

You can start with `locate libcublas.so` on both machines to see if there's a difference. Alternatively, you can `strace -f -e open` the program to check where it tries to `libcublas.so` from.

Your error has (for now) nothing to do with GPUs: `libcublas.so.9.0` can just not be found. Find it, find why Tensorflow can not find it and your problem will be solved.

Comment: I followed the step you mentioned. There is indeed some difference in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*. I would also like to mention that the command failed regardless of whether I ran Tensorflow or not. It failed on every cuda program, even the simple ones I created on my own without other lib dependencies. To be more specific, I tried the matrixMul program from cuda-samples. I can see the program started executing but as soon as it reaches a cuda call it returns error code 11. Any idea what this error represents?

Comment: After some careful searching I do find the answer here: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1045430/nsight-compute-/partial-profiling/ It appears GP100 is not supported for some reason. But thanks for the reply.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, I did not even pay attention to what GPU it was, as the original problem was about loading a shared library...